# Site is not indexed on Bing

Tags: seo, bing, bing-webmaster-tools

My site is having a good ranking on google, but the site is not even indexed in yahoo and bing.

I have submitted my site to both yahoo and bing search engines 3 months ago. I also submitted the sitemap of my site to bing webmaster tools.

Even so, I don't find the site to be indexed. I want the site to be indexed on both yahoo and bing.

Comment: Yahoo! == Bing (FYI)

Comment: Yep, and the joy of it is we now get Bahoo! and Ying! both indexing our site for a supposed combined result on Bing. Wish the search reasults were better for the severe hammering both bots can give your site. Google has always been less of a stress test. The Bing Webmaster Throttle was the best thing to ever happen to MSNBot/BingBot.

Answer (score 2):

My Basic Bing Experiences as follows:

Have you signed up with Bing's webmaster tools?

Have you verified ownership and submitted a sitemap to Bing?

Has the sitemap been scanned and are the number of pages in it being reported?

Till you do the above, it's kind of pointless waiting for anything to happen and **after** you do it, its pointless expecting anything until the site's been scanned for about six months.

Bing has always been pretty lax about indexing our website. For every three pages Google reports, you may have only one in Bing. After a year, they seem to ramp up and then average indexing about 80% of the pages on your site. Finally after two years, we've hit 98%.

Don't use the Crawl-delay in your robots.txt to slow down Bing's scan rate, manage bot throttling through their tool in the webmaster tools and commesurate for any throttling you do during your customer's primetime use, give more access during the off hours. The Bing of today might be different from the Live Search it used to be known as, but back then, throttling through robots.txt crawl-delay caused our indexed page count to drop off.

As a contrast, Google had our website redesign completely reindexed in a month and hit 99% pagecount indexed at two months.

Answer (score 1):

According to both sites help, if your site doesn't appear, it may be due to one of three things, not enough time yet, bad content/quality, malware. Check you content, and be sure that it's not the same as other competitors.

I recommend that you check your webmaster tools to check for any message from them if there is nothing there, and no errors are reported, check their forums.

Your robots.txt is not blocking any crawler and you don't have any robots prohibiting the index process, so, your are not intentionally blocking anything, that's a first step.